# Preferable method for reading N bytes from a file, then convert to an integer

Tags: c, file, fread

I'm trying to write an easy function for disk access, like the following, and can't decide what's *appropriate*; casting the buffer into the data type or do some bitwise byte-by-byte. In the future i'm planning to make it more endianess-friendly so what to choose? Any obvious reason why one of them is *prefered* ?

```
#include <pstdint.h>

...

uint16_t file_read_int8(FILE* fp) {
   char buffer[2];
   fread(buffer,1,2,file);

   // this?
   return *((uint16_t *)buffer);

   // or this?
   return buffer[0] | (buffer[1]<<8);
}
```

Comment: neither will work correctly.  Rather use something like char buffer[3] = {0}' ... return atoi( buffer );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either can work. The first one assumes the same architecture was used to both read and write the file (big-endian vs. little-endian). The second one does not make that assumption--it assumes little-endian (Intel) format. The first option may be faster, depending on how good your optimizer is (or isn't). I would think the second one would be preferred since it should work on any architecture and therefore allows the file format to be "cross-platform"--meaning either architecture could have created the file and either architecture could read the file.

Comment: Thank you. So you saying the casting will work regardless the cpu's architecture?

Comment: nevermind the previous comment ;) i also prefer the second one because it can manipulate the bytes. So working with bytes is the safest way, thank you